# How can I have different colors for a text lines?

Tags: html

I have a conversation and want to show it inside an html scrollable area.I want to show the lines of conversation with two colors.Something like this:

```
<em>A:</em> Hello</font><br><font color="green">
<em>B:</em> Hi</font><br><font color="blue">
<em>A:</em> How old are you?</font><br><font color="green">
<em>B:</em> I'm 17 years old.</font><br><font color="blue"><em>
```

And I want "A" sentences to be blue and "B" sentences to be green.Does anybody know what is the best element for this and how should I do this?

Comment: Can you put in your question your html code?

Comment: Why don't you research something like that yourself?

Comment: Any element (p, div) would be appropriate. The color also can be set through inline style or css classes. You should search it a little bit more before you ask a question. It's like you just posted your excersice title and want from others to give you the answer. This won't help you.

Comment: Obviously the edit answers your question. Though some elements aren't really where they were suppose to be and you could go and do that with less elements. Try doing that for exercise... :)

Comment: @AnastasiosSelmanis I've just updated the formatting of the question, i.e. without adding any HTML. The `font` tags were there in the question as it was posted.

Comment: `<font>` is not supported in html5. Use css-styling instead! Something like `<div style='color: #000;'>`.

Comment: @NisargShah sorry I saw the edit and I thought you inserted the elements as a quick answer or something like that. However I just told sun to exercise with it in order to start gaining some knowledge from this question. Until now it seems all of us have devoted more time in this questiion than the person asking the question himself

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is ... awful !
Here are some tips to improve it :

- Use CSS for styling your elements
- Avoid using `<br/>` as it is a "style tag"
- Wrap your elements in inline / block tags

So basically, your HTML structure would look like this :

```
<p class="green"><em>A:</em> Hello</p>
<p class="blue"><em>B:</em> Hi</p>
<p class="green"><em>A:</em> How old are you?</p>
<p class="blue"><em>B:</em> I'm 17 years old.</p>

<style type="text/css">
/* Create a margin under the 'p' tag to avoid use of <br/>*/
p {
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.blue {
    color:#0000FF;
}
.green {
    color:#00FF00;
}
</style>
```

I advise you to write your CSS in a dedicated stylesheet though.
More info about CSS classes [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_class.asp).

Comment: I don't think the element p needs a margin-bottom to avoid the <br />. It allways starts in a new row.

Comment: Yes you are right. I assumed he wanted to have extra space between his "p" tags.